# How do I go about debugging a PHP error?

Tags: web-development, php, debugging, error-handling

I am coming from .NET to PHP. I am playing around with a long file written by someone else (called "cryptographp.inc.php"). It builds and returns an image to the browser.

I want to show the image that the file returns on my Cryptocode/index.php page--like this:

```
<?php
include './cryptographp.inc.php'; 
?>
```

But when I load the page, firefox returns an error saying

```
"The image http://localhost/Cryptocode cannot be displayed because it
contains errors"
```

How would I go about debugging an error like this in PHP? I am used to stepping through code in visual studio. What techniques would people use in the PHP world?

Answer (score 4):

**In short:** I would start by enabling my development environment to catch the errors. There are some setting you would need to set.

For the **syntax errors**, you need to enable error display in the php.ini. By default these are turned off because you don't want a **customer** seeing the error messages. [Check this page](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) in the PHP documentation for information on the 2 directives: `error_reporting` and `display_errors`. `display_errors` is probably the one you want to change. If you can't modify the php.ini, you can also add the following lines to an .htaccess file:

```
php_flag  display_errors        on
php_value error_reporting       2039
```

You may want to consider using the value of E_ALL (as mentioned by Gumbo) for your version of PHP for `error_reporing` to get all of the errors. [more info](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

Three important points to consider:

1. Check the error log file as it will have all of the errors (unless logging has been disabled).
2. Adding the following 2 lines will help to debug errors that are not syntax errors:

   error_reporting(-1);
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
3. Use an editor that checks for errors why you type, such as [**PhpEd**](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped.htm). It also comes with a debugger which can provide more detailed information. (The PhpEd debugger is very similar to xdebug and integrates directly into the editor so you use one program to do everything). The "[xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/)" will make your reports much nicer as well.

Cartman's [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/) also has very good guidelines to follow: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/

**References and blog posts:**

- [How to Debug in PHP](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php)
- [Turning on PHP Debugging and Error Messages](http://motoma.io/turning-on-php-debugging-and-error-messages/)
- [Mediawiki - PHP Errors](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHow_to_debug)

Comment: Another good IDE to use for PHP develoment is [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) by JetBrains.  It has syntax highlighting and checking, auto-completion, debug features (including an interface with xdebug) etc.  I have no connection with the company, just a happy customer for several years.

Comment: you might want to set the error_reporting value in htaccess/apache to 2147483647 - it's a bitmask, and the exact [flags change between different versions of PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)